# XNA Move List of Rectangles

Tags: xna-4.0

I have a game in which sprites will be removed and added under different circumstances, and so I created `Rects` of type `List<Rectangle>` to hold the bounding rectangle for each sprite.

```
List<Rectangle> Rects = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Within `Initialize()`:

```
playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
cowTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cow");
player = new Player(playerTexture, new Vector2(100, 100));
Rects.Add(player.Bounds);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Cow cow = new Cow(cowTexture, graphics);
    cows.Add(cow);
    Rects.Add(cows[i].Bounds);
}
```

What I want to do is iterate through every rectangle in the list and move it when the player approaches the edge of the screen. This is the code with which I have tried to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rects.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.Bounds.Left < 60)
    {
        Rects[i].Offset(2, 0);
    }
    if (player.Bounds.Right > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - 30)
    {
        Rects[i].Offset(-2, 0);
    }
    if (player.Bounds.Top < 60)
    {
        Rects[i].Offset(0, 2);
    }
    if (player.Bounds.Bottom > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - 30)
    {
        Rects[i].Offset(0, -2);
    }
}
```

But when my player gets to the edge of the screen, he very happily leaves and none of the sprites move. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're **copying** the `cows[i].Bounds` rectangles to your `Rects` list. Your loop is just updating the copy, not the original - your original `Cow` will not be modified in this way. `Rectangle` is a struct, not a class, so it's copied by value to the list, not as a reference.

Also, your loop design is *very* inefficient, in that you're checking the GraphicsDevice settings multiple times per per loop. Try this instead:

```
Point offset;

if (player.Bounds.Left < 60)
   offset.X = 2;
else if (player.Bounds.Right > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - 30)
  offset.X = -2;

if (player.Bounds.Top < 60)
   offset.Y = 2;
else if (player.Bounds.Bottom > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - 30)
    offsetY = -2;

if (offsetX != 0 || offsetY != 0)
   for(int i = 0; i < cows.Count; i++)
   {
    cows[i].Bounds.Offset(offset);
   }
```

Another potential issue:

Why are you offsetting by only 2? It may make more sense to offset the position based on the distance the sprite has moved outside of the view:

```
if (player.Bounds.Left < 60)
    offsetX = 60 - player.Bounds.Left;
```

... and so forth.

**Update**

Also, you're moving either `cows[]` or `rects[]`, based on whether `player` is near the edge of the viewport. Shouldn't you be moving `player` instead?

The logic above seems to do the following:

If the **player** is less than 60 units from the left or top of the viewport, or less than 30 units from the bottom or right of the viewport, move all of the **cows**.

If the player is moving, it willl happily keep moving, and not be adjusted relative to anything else. If you fix the `Rect` reference issue, I'd expect them to start moving when `player` hits your 60x30 margin, and for `player` to keep going in the direction it was before (right off of the screen).

If your units are pixels, and this is being called per frame, you'll also see some pretty dramatic velocity when the motion starts, which may or may not appear as a flicker followed by everything disappearing.

**Update the second**

In response to your comment,

> Are you saying that the only way to do this is to move cows[i].Bounds, player.Bounds, and any others separately?

In C++, you'd use a template for this. In C#, you'll need either an interface or a common base class. For example:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Rectangle Bounds;
}

public class Player : Entity
{
}

public class Cow : Entity
{
}

public class MyGame 
{
   public List<Entity> Entities { get; private set; }

   public MyGame()
   {
       Entities = new List<Entity>();
   }
}
```

And, create some players and cows at some point in your application

```
void Initialize()
{
    /// add 4 players
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var player = new Player();

        player.Bounds = new Rectangle(.....)

        Entities.Add(player);
    }

    /// add some cows
    for(var i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var cow = new Cow();
        cow.Bounds = new Rectangle(..........(;
        Entities.Add(cow);
    }
}
```

In your update loop:

```
/// later on, move everything
for(var i = 0; i < Entities.Count; i++)
{
    var item = Entities[i];
    item.Bounds.Offset(.....);
}
```

Comment: I originally moved the rectangle of each cow and the player individually, like you said, but I want to eventually add more things to the games, like different animals and enemies, and I did not want to have a separate loop for each type of character. I wanted to be able to move all of the rectangles in as few lines as possible, so I made a list of rectangles that includes the cows and the player, and anything else that I add later. However, I think you have answered my question. Are you saying that the only way to do this is to move `cows[i].Bounds`, `player.Bounds`, and any others separately?

Comment: Do these things have a common base class which defines .Bounds?

Comment: In both classes, Bounds is of type Rectangle.

Comment: Yes, but do they have a common **BASE** class? See update.

Comment: And by "they", I mean `Player` and `Cow`?

Comment: No, Player and Cow are base classes. I did not think of having them extend a common class.

Comment: Also, what does the `abstract` attribute actually do?

Comment: @Giaphage47 I hate to say this, but I recommend that you have a look at an introductory C# tutorial to get familiar with this kind of thing. But `abstract` indicates that a type cannot be directly instantiated - only it's descendents can. In this case you can `new Cow()` or `new Player()`, but not `new Entity()` as it will generate a compiler error.

Comment: I had never actually seen the attribute used before, and was not sure whether that was the only thing it did. I am taking a C# class, but as when I was learning java and c++, the only way I have found to actually understand what I am being taught is to try to use a concept right after hearing it. I asked my teacher, and he said he was just as unfamiliar with inheritance in C# as I was...

Comment: @Giaphage47 OUCH. Perhaps he should not be teaching this class. (I teach game dev at a university - there are topics I admit I'm not qualified to teach. )

Comment: @Giaphage47 Also, that's a good way to learn things. When we want to teach someone to play baseball, we go to the park and hit some balls. When we teach engineering, we sit around and talk it about it for four-five years. And we wonder why 90% of products fail to ship.